# Upper bound for residue of a rational function with zeros and poles in the disk

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, residue-calculus, rational-functions, meromorphic-functions

Let $r(z)$ be a monic rational function (that is, a ratio of monic polynomials) all of whose finite zeros and poles lie in the unit disk of degree $n$.

**QUESTION**: Is there a nice upper bound on the residues of $r$ at its poles, perhaps in terms of $n$, but independent of the locations of its zeros and poles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such bound independent of the location of zeros
and poles. Consider for example
$$
 r(z) = \frac{z^n}{(z-a)(z-b)^{n-1}}
$$
with $a,b \in \Bbb D \setminus \{ 0 \}$. $r$ has a simple pole at $z=a$ with residue
$$
 \frac{a^n}{(a-b)^{n-1}}
$$
and that becomes arbitrarily large when choosing $b$ close to $a$.